# Mac OS 10.13.5 npm and node complete uninstall is failing

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

As per link [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x), I've tried all the options

But even after that, when I goto command prompt and checked `node -v` and `npm -v`, it shows some version.  I'm not getting what is going wrong.

I've deleted node_modules folders under `/Users/$username`

Comment: Can you check `which node` command to see which path you have this coming from?

Comment: /usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node, should I delete "node@10" folder ?

Comment: Yeah - Let's start with removing this folder.

Comment: ok, now it worked properly. Can you please give reference to this suggestion ? Also as mentioned I have deleted "node_modules" under /Users/$username, please confirm it won't have any adverse effect.

Comment: The removal of `node_modules` should not have any effect. I didn't get the part on "reference to this suggestion"?

Comment: I meant from where did you find solution of deleting "node@10" folder ? I couldn't find it anywhere on SO

Comment: Ahh, I didn't. I just suggested to look for which `node` executable was still there. It turned out `node@10`. I can put this out in an answer if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking with `which node` to find the full path executable ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(command))).

Once you have the location you can remove the folder and that should help removing the last instance of node still available on your machine.